# Compiling *.mm with GCC

Tags: objective-c, c, gcc

I'm making a very simple Objective-C/C program in a .mm file but I don't know how to link the Objective-C libraries/frameworks. I only need the Foundation framework. How can I do this? I don't want to do this in Xcode because Xcode always creates an entire folder with project files and then buries the product in a hard-to-find folder and I feel that it is a lot of memory used for a one-file program.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSString* charToNSString(char * c){
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:c];
}

const char* NSStringToChar(NSString *str){
    return [str UTF8String];
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling: `gcc file.mm`

Output:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSString", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in file-4bd3e4.o
  "_objc_msgSend", referenced from:
      charToNSString(char*) in file-4bd3e4.o
      NSStringToChar(NSString*) in file-4bd3e4.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: `-framework Foundation`

Comment: You also need to either use `clang++` instead of `clang` or add `-lstdc++` to the command line if you use any pieces of the C++ standard library, otherwise you'll get linker errors for that as well.  If you're using pure Objective-C instead of Objective-C++, then you should use the `.m` file extension instead of `.mm`.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Can I have Objective-C and plain C in one *.m file? Don't *.m files need a corresponding header?

Comment: Objective-C is a superset of plain C, so if you use Objective-C, you are already having both in one *m file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ gcc -framework Foundation main.mm
```

Although above command works perfectly, but I suggest you to create Makefile

```
$vim Makefile
```

paste the content below

```
CC=gcc

FRAMEWORKS:= -framework Foundation

SOURCE=main.mm

OUT=-o main

all:
        $(CC) $(SOURCE) $(FRAMEWORKS) $(OUT)
#   ^ this is a tab not spaces, if you give spaces here it will through error :*** missing separator
```

then run

```
$ make
```

Just look at this simple tutorial about [Makefile](http://codeseekah.com/2012/09/12/compiling-objective-c-without-a-gui/)

Comment: Other than a one-word compile command are there any advantages to using `make` and MakeFile over `gcc`?

Comment: Yes there are many benefits, you have only single source file and thus making a `Makefile` doesn't make sense, but as project size increases it becomes more tedious also you can specify targets in `Makefile`. You can read a good blog about it [Why use Makefile](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/make/)

Comment: OMG! **Is there any way to let `gcc` detect the `mm` file's used frameworks?** I mean, Xcode seems to detect those somehow automatically.

Comment: With C and Objective-C, Clang can use module map files to determine which framework or library to link against. However, C++ support of modules isn't there yet, so Objective-C++ (and C++) can't auto-link libraries/frameworks yet.